# How to show different tooltips for the buttons in the PrimeFaces RowEditor

Tags: primefaces, tooltip, editor

I use `<p:rowEditor />` in my `<p:dataTable>` and I want to add tooltip for this component.

I have problem because in default PrimeFaces display same tooltip for "pencil" icon, "ok" icon and "close" icon too.

How i can set separate tooltip for each icon?

My code:

```
<p:dataTable>
    <p:column>
        ...
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        ...
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        ...
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        ...
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{stat.validTo}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:calendar value="#{stat.validTo}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" mask="true"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        ...
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:rowEditor id="row-editor" />
        <p:tooltip id="row-editor-tooltip" for="row-editor" value="Edit" position="right"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: nice question, can you show us your code please?

Answer (score 2):

The `<p:rowEditor/>` component has 3 attributes that solves your problem and it can be used as follows:

`<p:rowEditor editTitle ="Edit" saveTitle="Save" cancelTitle="Cancel" />`

If your IDE doesn't give you suggestions for the existing attributes, you can check the Primefaces User Guide for the version you use.